# Finding a transformation matrix that change a matrix to an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

**Problem:** Given a matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Find a transformation matrix $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ such that
$$\dfrac{1}{m}\Theta^TY^T Y\Theta=I_{p\times p},$$
where $I_{p\times p}$ is identity matrix.

**My attempt:** I realized that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{m}}Y\Theta$ is orthogonal matrix and tried to find $\Theta$ satisfies it but that doesn't work.

Comment: Warning: To most mathematicians, an orthogonal matrix is square.

Comment: Agreed.  [Semi-orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix)  is a more accurate description.

Answer (score 2):

This can only work if $Y$ has full rank. Now $\Theta$ could perform the basis transformation from the Gram-Schmidt procedure.